# Sitefinity 404 Multilingual Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, sitefinity

So I have a Sitefinity instance with a custom error page, but for some reason it's not correctly rendering the correct page's language. It always defaults to the main one (english), when it should render the french page when the user is on the french version of the site.

Now... I've followed this [Sitefinity Doc](https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-create-a-custom-404-error-page-in-multisite-or-multilingual-environment), but it's still not working as it should.

My HTTPErrors section in web.config

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
  <clear />
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

---

```
private readonly string errorPageName = "Error";

protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Contains("Error")) // URL of 404 page
    {
        return;
    }

    var ex = (HttpException)this.Server.GetLastError();
    int httpCode = ex.GetHttpCode();

    if (httpCode == 404)
    {
        //this.Handle404();
        this.Handle404WithSitefinityPage(this.errorPageName);
    }
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Contains("Error")) // URL of 404 page
    {
        return;
    }

    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    int httpCode = response.StatusCode;

    if (httpCode == 404)
    {
        this.Handle404WithSitefinityPage(this.errorPageName);
        //this.Handle404();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles error for both multisite and singlesite modes regardles of culture
/// This methods gets a Sitefinity page and renders it's content without rewriting the current 
/// URL, does not issue a 301/302 redirect to the acutal 404 (the actual 404 page will return http 200 code)
///  </summary>
/// <param name="sitefinity404PageTitle"></param>
protected void Handle404WithSitefinityPage(string sitefinity404PageTitle)
{
    this.Server.ClearError();

    PageManager manager = PageManager.GetManager();

    // This call will get the correct page in multisite and multinglual mode
    PageNode pageNode = manager
        .GetPageNodes()
        .First(x => x.Title.Contains(sitefinity404PageTitle));

    PageData pd = pageNode.GetPageData(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
    pageNode = pd.NavigationNode;

    this.Response.StatusCode = 404;

    // The InMemoryPageRender has some limitations, it does not render navigations 
    // widgets, it does not aways include JS that come from widgets
    // Error pages created to be used by this logic must be plain and not have
    // heavy JS dependencies
    string content = new InMemoryPageRender().RenderPage(pageNode);
    this.Response.Write(content);

    this.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Using breakpoints, it seems to be retrieving the correct language specific page, but on the client it defaults to the english one no matter what.

Comment: /error is a Sitefinity page which has both english and french translations.